# Should folders like /usr/local/bin be in $PATH? (macOSX)

Tags: path, environment-variables

Do people have directories like /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin be in $PATH since it is usually used when installing new packages through pip and stuff?

I was wondering if it is a good practice to include this to avoid future problems.

Comment: You said in a comment to my answer: "I've been having many issues installing packages...". Which means you should have asked "Why am I getting these errors when I run `brew` and `pip`?" You assumed the presence of */usr/local/bin* in your `PATH` var was the problem. That is unlikely to be true if you ignore the command search order aspect of this type of problem. That is, more than one command of the same name in different `PATH` directories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, people put */usr/local/bin* in `PATH`. Especially since most macOS users who work from a shell CLI are likely to be using HomeBrew to install things and it's default location is */usr/local/bin*. I can't help but wonder if you meant to ask something else.

Comment: I've been having many issues installing packagest through homebrew and pip... so I wondered if the path is messed up.

Comment: Your `PATH` value might be messed up. But not simply because you include */usr/local/bin* in it. You can have multiple commands by the same name in different `PATH` directories. The first one found is used. That can cause problems. But I doubt that is your problem. You mention `pip` so I can't help but wonder if you really have a python issue about dealing with multiple python ecosystems.